# SendGridMessage E-mails with Attachement

Tags: c#, azure, email

I have a Kendo Upload which uploads documents to an Azure blob. I want to send and e-mail with an attachement with a document uploaded with Kendo.
Here is what I tried:

```
   System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase doc;
            string filepath;
            string uniqueBlobName;

            public ActionResult UploadRegistry()
            {
                doc = Request.Files["Registry"];
                var inputstream = doc.InputStream;
                var filename = doc.FileName;
                var doctype = doc.ContentType;
                var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AzureStorageConnection"].ConnectionString);
                CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("registrynumber");
                container.CreateIfNotExists();
                var permission = container.GetPermissions();
                uniqueBlobName = string.Format("Document/{0}", filename);
                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(uniqueBlobName);
                blob.Properties.ContentType = doctype;
                blob.UploadFromStream(inputstream);
                filepath = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
                TempData["Document"] = doc.FileName;
                TempData["Document1"] = filepath;
                string address ="test.test@test.com";

                var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

                var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();

                // Add the message properties.
                myMessage.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com", "Test");

                myMessage.AddAttachment(filepath);
                myMessage.AddTo(address);
                myMessage.Subject = "Document";
                var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);


              var x = transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage);


                return Json(new { success = true });

            }
```

Later, I get an error that the filepath is invalid. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code and description, I found you directly use the uploaded path(url) as the AddAttachment parameter.

As far as I know, the SendGridMessage.AddAttachment method doesn't support directly send the email with online resources.

So you will face the filepath is invalid error. The details error is like as below:

[image]

Besides, I found you use stream to upload file to the azure blob storage.

The SendGridMessage.AddAttachment method also support add stream as its parameters.

So I suggest you could change the codes as below, it will work well.

```
         myMessage.From = new MailAddress("test@test.com", "Test");

            myMessage.AddAttachment(inputstream,doc.FileName);
            myMessage.AddTo(address);
            myMessage.Subject = "Document";
            var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
```

My test codes is like below:

Notice: I directly read file stream as the parameter.

```
    static  void  ExecuteAsync(Customer customer)
    {
        using (Stream s1 = File.OpenRead(@"D:\toekn.txt"))
        {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connectionstring");
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("mycontainer");
        container.CreateIfNotExists();
        var permission = container.GetPermissions();

        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("aaaa.txt");

        blob.UploadFromStream(s1);
        string  filepath = blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        var credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
         var myMessage = new SendGridMessage();
        string address = "aaaaa@gmail.com";

        // Add the message properties.
        myMessage.From = new MailAddress("bbbbbb@hotmail.com", "Example User");
        myMessage.Subject = "Sending with SendGrid is Fun";
        myMessage.Text = "and easy to do anywhere, even with C#";
       // myMessage.AddAttachment(s1, "11.txt");
        myMessage.AddAttachment(filepath);
        myMessage.AddTo(address);
        myMessage.Subject = "Document";
        var transportWeb = new Web(credentials);
         transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage).Wait();
        }         
    }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Have you check this [url](https://app.sendgrid.com/email_activity)? Does it has the send email logs?

Comment: No, no data is displayed.

Comment: Have you tired "transportWeb.DeliverAsync(myMessage).Wait()" this code?  If you don't send successfully, I think it will give you the error message.

Comment: What means Result:Not Computed yet?

Comment: Do you mean the result is this? {Id = 1, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}. This means the codes is still run and doesn't return the result. I suggest you could try my codes to wait the codes executed completely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154311/discussion-between-brando-zhang-and-george-great).

Comment: Now, the issue seems you couldn't send the email. I suggest you could firstly remove the Attachement and try again.
Besides, could you please post the details error message?